# How do I create a preface in LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, structure

I am wondering on how I could insert a preface before the table of contents.
The page would be roman enumerated but not put in the actual table of content. The initial part of my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\documentclass[12pt, openright ]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\

begin{titlepage}
    \pagenumbering{Roman} 

Title


    \end{titlepage}

    \shipout\null

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Comment: Welome to tex.sx.  Your example isn't going to work -- only one document class can be used for a single document.  However, assuming you mean the `book` class, the usual method of including a preface is to input `\chapter*{Preface} \clearpage` before `\tableofcontents` (if that's where you want it; in some fields, it's more common after all those tables).  There's a bit more involved, but it does depend on what document class you are using.

Comment: `\shipout\null`? Are you *really* sure?

Comment: I would like to keep the article class, it is better for what I am doing. I was just thinking about adding an extra page before with the title:Preface and writing in there. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new environment is way overkill in my opinion. Simply add `\chapter*{Preface}` or `\section*{Preface}` before `\tableofcontents`. By adding `*` to chapters and sections they get ignored by the table of contents.

Comment: Often one would want the Preface to be listed in the TOC but, of course, be unnumbered.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use this code to define a preface environment

```
% ===== Define a preface environment =====
\newcommand{\prefacename}{Preface}
\newenvironment{preface}{
    \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
    {\noindent \bfseries \Huge \prefacename}
    \begin{center}
        % \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\prefacename} % enable this if you want to put the preface in the table of contents
        \thispagestyle{plain}
    \end{center}%
}
{\vspace*{\stretch{5}}}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}



\usepackage{tocloft}


    % ===== Define abstract environment =====
    \newcommand{\prefacename}{Preface}
    \newenvironment{preface}{
        \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
        {\noindent \bfseries \Huge \prefacename}
        \begin{center}
            % \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\prefacename} % enable this if you want to put the preface in the table of contents
            \thispagestyle{plain}
        \end{center}%
    }
    {\vspace*{\stretch{5}}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{titlepage}

Title

\end{titlepage}

\shipout\null

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman} 

\begin{preface}
    \blindtext
\end{preface}

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\listoftables



\mainmatter

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: actually the phantomsection command is very inspiring. gotta add this to my list of latex commands. defining a environment for prefaces should be overkill though in my opinion.